# cassandra backup - errors during compression

Tags: backup, database-backup, cassandra

My cassandra backup often returns with errors because users move/change it during the compression (we just tar it). Users are logged to the server 24/7 so we can't just change backup hours.
I need some ideas/solutions how to avoid those errors or a better way for cassandra backups.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do the backup on the real data, but instead you need to create snapshot of the data on server using the `nodetool snapshot`, and do backup from it. After you finished the backup, you can clear snapshots using the `nodetool clearsnapshot`.  For better understanding on how backup and restore works, please look to [this DataStax support article](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001593706-Manual-Backup-and-Restore-with-Point-in-time-and-table-level-restore-).